# How to remove transition delay on vue transition?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, css-animations

I'm using vue  to animate moving a textbox upwards and fading in the textbox when an image is hovered over. The animation is correct, but there is a slight delay for it to start. I want the textbox to smoothly and instantly start fading in and moving upwards upon image hover. When the cursor leaves the textbox fades out and move down correctly.

```
template: `
            <div>
                <div class="attribute-icons" v-for="(item, i) in techBadges" :key="'tech_' + i">
                    <img @mouseenter="hoverStart(i)" @mouseleave="hoverEnd" class="attribute-icon" width="30px" height="30px" :src="badges[item].imageSrc" :alt="badges[item].alt"/>
                    <Transition>
                        <p v-show="hoveredIndex === i">{{ badges[item].description }}</p>
                    </Transition>
                </div>
            </div>
        `,
        methods:{
            hoverStart(i){
                this.hoveredIndex = i;
            },
            hoverEnd(){
                this.hoveredIndex = null;
            }
        },
```

```
.attribute-icons {
                    margin-top: 5px;
                    position:relative;
                    transition-delay: 0s;

                    img {
                        width: 28px;
                        height: 28px;
                        margin-right: 8px;
                        transition: 0.24s;
                        transition-delay: 0s;
                        
                    }

                    p {
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 20px;
                        width:19vw;
                        max-width:350px;
                        min-width:175px;
                        background: #0088ce;
                        color: #ffffff;
                        z-index: 1;
                        border-radius: 5px;
                        padding: 5px 10px;
                        box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(2, 2, 2, 0.14);
                        pointer-events: none;
                        font-weight: 500;
                        font-size: 13px;
                        transition: 0.24s ease;
                        transition-delay: 0s;
                        @media(max-width:1100px){
                            width:25vw;
                        }
                        @media(max-width:991px){
                            width:36vw;
                        }

                    }

                    .v-enter-from{
                        opacity: 0;
                        transform: translateY(10px);
                        transition: opacity 0.24s ease, transform 0.24s ease;
                        transition-delay: 0s;
                    };
                    .v-enter-active{
                        transition-delay: 0s;
                        transition: opacity 0.24s ease, transform 0.24s ease;
                        transform: translateY(4px);
                    };
                    .v-enter-to{

                    };

                    .v-leave-from{
                        transform: translateY(10px);
                    };
                    .v-leave-active{
                        transition: opacity 0.24s ease, transform 0.24s ease;
                        transform: translateY(10px);
                    };
                    .v-leave-to{
                        opacity:0;
                    };
```

I've tried adding transition-delay: 0s to all elements and it did not work